# ansible 2.4 (python 2.7.5) and ansible 2.6 (python 3.6.3) dictionary syntax difference?

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

On server 1 i have ansible 2.4.2.0 with python version = 2.7.5 :

On server 2 i have ansible 2.6.0 with python version = 3.6.3 :

on Server 1, this works fine , by calling a dictionary ***roles/webapp/defaults/main.yml*** inside ***roles/webapp/vars/main.yml***:

```
nexus_download_url: '{{ nexus_redirect_base_url }}?r={{ nexus_repo_name }}&g={{ apps[application_name].artifact_group_id }}&a={{ application_name }}&v={{ application_version }}&c=exec&e=jar'
```

While on server 2 i get following error :

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute...}
```

The issue is linked to :

```
&g={{ apps[application_name].artifact_group_id }}
```

Is there any modifications done between the two ansible version on dictionary syntax , i didn't find anything on ansible changelog for both version 2.5 and 2.6 ?

Comment: It's not an answer but wanted to confirm if we specify the nexus_download_url within " "(double quotes)

Comment: yes we do when passing parameter to playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried two things and it worked :

1. Adding the dictionary directly inside ***/role/test/vars/main.yml***
2. add to the ansible config file (ansible.cfg)

   hash_behaviour = merge